# How do you earn reputation if you cannot do anything because you have none?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

How do you earn points on this website if you literally cannot do anything unless you have points?

[Can't even post this question on the place it belongs BECAUSE I HAVE NO POINTS.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F3ob.png)

Comment: Alright thanks guys, I can at least participate in Meta now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer questions and ask [smart questions](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: When I try to answer a question, it says I need more points.

Comment: Aaaand now I can answer questions, I guess the rep from this question gave me the power to do so. So this is answered now I guess.

Comment: Now we both have more points. Thank you

Comment: Accept the answer by clicking the checkmark and you'll both get some reputation.

Comment: @Ryval Protected questions (which are protected because they have historically attracted lots of low-quality answers) require 10 rep to answer, but other than that asking and answering on the main site does not require any reputation.